# Date UTC in Flex

Tags: java, actionscript-3, date, apache-flex

I have an application in Flex with Java backend.

In this application , I have a java rest service that returns a date of birth . On the java side , this data is returned as, for example, 10/10/2000. The problem is that when this date arrives on the Flex side , it comes as 09/10/2000. I debug the date in Flex, and realized that the 'dateUTC' attribute is 10, but the 'date' attribute is 09. Why these two attributes are different?

This problem only happens with dates between 10/10/2000 and 10/22/2000 . Has anyone experienced this kind of thing?

Thank you.

Comment: I had a similar problem once: it was due to DST. Each date in winter on the Java side ended up the day before on the Flex side because one hour was subtracted from the date by Flex (and then the time part was removed). The only solution I found was to pass the dates as String...

Comment: In return the flex , I added one hour to dates of birth, and the problem was solved .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the problem by adding one hour on birthdates on flex side.

Comment: Your solution is locale-specific. It will produce errors sooner or later.